# What is µ A below ~ x in the Fuzzy Logic

Tags: fuzzy-logic

I am reading the book "Fuzzy Logic with Engineering" written by Timothy J. Ross and there is a phrase in the book at page 90, he mentions about the "Features of the Membership Function". He says:

> The support of a membership function for some fuzzy set A under ~ is
>   defined as that region of the universe that is characterized by
>   nonzero membership in the set A under ~. That is, the support
>   comprises  those elements x of the universe such that μ A under ~
>   (x)>0.

He denotes it as a graphical representation:

[image]

what is μ A under ~ (x) in this context?  Thanks in advance.

Edit Post
The μ A under ~ (x) in this context is membership function. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fuzzy_logic/fuzzy_logic_membership_function.htm

Comment: The picture is pretty clear: the support of $A$ is the set of $x$ such that $\mu(x) > 0$. The core is the set of $x$ such that $\mu(x) = 1$, and the boundary is the set of $x$ such that $0 < \mu(x) < 1$.

Comment: What is the definition of μ?

Comment: I have no idea, since I don't have access to the book. However, I am certain that $\mu$ is defined in the book, moreover in the first 90 pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here μ A˜(∙) μA~(∙) membership function of A˜ this assumes values in the range from 0 to 1, i.e.,  μ A ˜ (∙)∈[0,1] μA~(∙)∈[0,1] . The membership function  μ A ˜ 
(∙)  μA~(∙) maps   U to the membership space M . The dot  (∙) in the membership function described above, represents the element in a fuzzy set; whether it is discrete or continuous.

In classical set theory, it is either 1 or 0.

source:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/fuzzy_logic/fuzzy_logic_membership_function.htm